# Arrays concatenation in AngularJS and owl-carousel environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel

I'm trying to load an carousel with angularjs using owl-carousel. I want my carousel to scroll endless, loading items every time the list is fully scrolled and adding queried elements to the actual list. My issue is:

When I get data from the controller of the next page, I want to merge and contact the received items to be merged the the current array and be rendered at the end of the carousel, here is what I've done:

```
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="{navigation: true, pagination: false, rewindNav : false}">
        <div  owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="item in hmc.ProductData.Products track by $index" class="item">
          <a ng-href="/#!//{{Page.Culture+'/product/'+item.id}}">
            <div class="telewebion-show-box one-row">
              <div class="telewebion-show-box-cover">
                <ul>
                  <li>{{::item.title}}</li>
                  <li>{{::item.price}}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <img ng-src="{{::item.picture_path}}" width="220" height="148"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </data-owl-carousel>
```

And here is my controller:

```
hmc.getProducts=function(){
    ProductFactory.getProducts(hmc.ProductData.Offset,hmc.ProductData.Limit).then(function(Products){
      if(hmc.ProductData.Page==0)
      {
        hmc.ProductData.Products[0]='';
      }
      hmc.ProductData.Page++;
      var tempArray=[];
      tempArray.push(Products);
      console.log(tempArray);
      hmc.ProductData.Products [0]=hmc.ProductData.Products [0].concat(tempArray[0]);
      console.log(hmc.ProductData.Products );
      hmc.ProductData.UpdateInProgress=false;
    });
  }
```

but it doesn't contact and merge the array and wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just did it like this:

```
hmc.ProductData.Page++;
      var tempArray=[];
      var tempArray2=[];
      tempArray.push(AjaxProducts);
      tempArray2.push(hmc.ProductData.Products);
      hmc.ProductData.Products= tempArray2[0].concat(tempArray[0]);
      tempArray.length = 0;
      tempArray2.length = 0;
```

Now angular ng-repeat just repeat in a single array structure and ajax appends to the end of that array

Answer (score 1):

With `tempArray.push(Products);` you push a single array, considered as the whole variable, in a single cell of the array `tempArray` without obtaining the expected result. You should call:

```
 tempArray =  tempArray.concat(Products);
```

This way you push every element of `Products` in `tempArray`. Please note that concat does not modify the calling array directly, this behavior force you to reassign its return value to the original `tempArray`.